# Invalid literal for int with base 10: ''

Tags: python, casting, slice

```
>>> n = ''.join(i for i in x if i.isdigit())
>>> n.isdigit()
True
>>> x.isdigit()
False

>>> previous = 0
>>> next = 100
>>> answer = 0


>>> for i in range(0,100):
...     answer += int(n[previous:next])
...     previous = next
...     next += 100
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Why am I getting this error ? As you can see n is digit..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`n` might be numeric, but at some stage you're going past the length of `n` such that `n[previous:next]` contains no characters at all. The empty string `''` cannot be converted to an int, hence the error which tells the full story: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`.

```
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Well, as you can I see I have removed everything from the string but the digits n = ''.join(i for i in x if i.isdigit()), didn't this do the job ?

Comment: @Marijus Removing non-digits is not going to prevent you from getting an empty string. An empty string contains "only digits", but is still not an integer.

Comment: That's why I used answer += int(n[previous:next])

Comment: @Marijus The problem lies in `int(n[previous:next])`, which is unrelated to the `+=`. Consider the string `n` being `'1234'` and taking `n[10:20]`. The result will be `''`.